# HDFS atomic rename file system dependency

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Other questions on stack-overflow as well as hadoop 2.x documentation state that the HDFS rename operation is atomic. But hadoop 2.x documentation states also the following:

> Note that atomicity of rename is dependent on the file system
>   implementation. Please refer to the file system documentation for
>   details
>   Source: [Hadoop 2.x FileContext documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileContext.html#rename(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.Rename...))

That phrase also implies a dependency to the underlying file system. Until know it was not possible for me to understand or elobarate the exact implication of that sentence. Is it just that the rename operation of the File-System must also be atomic ? What kinds of commonly used file systems are in conflict with that sentence ?

Answer (score 0):

DistributedFileSystem's rename seems to be atomic. There is a Javadoc comment for the `rename(Path src, Path dst, final Options.Rename... options)` method that says:

  `/** 
   * This rename operation is guaranteed to be atomic.
   */`

The [latest documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html#Core_Expectations_of_a_Hadoop_Compatible_FileSystem) also says that an atomic rename is one of the core expectations of a Hadoop-compatible FileSystem, so I would assume that frequently used FileSystems like WebHdfsFileSystem and S3FileSystem support atomic renames. The source code is a bit difficult to follow, so I'm not 100% sure.